# (standard_in) 1: syntax error in a bash script

Tags: bash, batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch script that takes as command line arguments two .cpp files, compiles them and then measure their execution times.

```
#!/bin/bash
error=0
g++ -O2 -std=c++11 $1 -o __gen
((error|=$?))
g++ -O2 -std=c++11 $2 -o __run
((error|=$?))
if (($error != 0)); then
    echo 'Compilation failed'
    rm __gen __run
    exit 1;
fi

clear
echo 'Compilation was succesful'

time=0.0
until (( `bc <<< "$time > 1.5"` )); do
    ./__gen > in
    time=$(/usr/bin/time -f "%e" ./__run < in > out)
done
```

The first .cpp is source code for a test generator. It produces input for the second program.  I want the batch to stop the first time the second program runs for more than 1.5 seconds.

When I run the script i get `(standard_in) 1: syntax error`.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command:

```
/usr/bin/time -f "%e" ./__run < in > out
```

Outputs nothing (because the whole stdout is redirected to file `out`, and the `time` command outputs the time to stderr).
Thus, the variable `time` becomes empty after the first iteration of the loop.
Then `"$time > 1.5"` evaluates to `> 1.5` which causes syntax error in `bc` (left operand of `>` is missing).

One solution would be to use the `-o` option of `/usr/bin/time` to write the time to a temporary file and later read that file into the variable.
This will also eliminate possible problems where the program `__run` also outputs data to stderr which would again spoil the input to `bc`.

Comment: Thank you! But how can I fix that? ./__run produces output that I don't want to be displayed in the terminal, neither go to time variable